# Two ways to calculate the same sum where the harmonic number pops up.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, harmonic-numbers

Can someone help me with this equality?

Prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i} = \sum_{i=1}^n {n \choose i}\frac{(x-1)^i}{i} + H_n$$
where $H_n$ is the harmonic number.

Comment: probably your index are from $i=1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: let the LHS be $L(x)$ and the RHS be $R(x)$. For proving $L(x)=R(x)$, it's sufficient to check that $L'(x)=R'(x)$ (done using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) and $L(1)=R(1)$ (done immediately).

Comment: what do you mean (using the binomial theorem)

Comment: @MadjidChergui: Did you find $R'(x)$?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i+1} (x-1)^i$