# $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}=H_n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}$

Tags: summation

Prove:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}=H_n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}$$

where $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k$

For the $x^k$ i tried  $x^k=((x-1)+1)^k$ and decompose it into binomial expansion but I got dual sum at the one side one sum at the other side

For the second method:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}=H_n$$

and try to show

$$\binom{n}{k}(x-1)^k-x^k=1$$

Either the problem is wrong or I cannot do it.

Comment: Putting $x = 1$ in your last equation shows that it is wrong.

Comment: In your second method you have the wrong order of terms on the left.

Comment: [Asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3903099) few hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think the identity does not hold. Using
$$ x^k=[1+(x-1)]^k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(1-x)^i=1+\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(1-x)^i $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}\\
&=&\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\bigg(1+\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{k}{i}(1-x)^i\bigg)\\
&=&H_n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i} \frac{(x-1)^i}{k}\\
&\neq&H_n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(x-1)^k}{k}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: If in your second-to-last line you switch the order of summation, you get $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k} = H_n + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{(x-1)^{i}}{i} \sum_{k = i}^{n} \binom{k-1}{i-1}\,.$$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanted to keep the same form.

Comment: Sorry, I was too opaque. Use the so-called Hockey-stick identity, and then rename $i$ to $k$.

Answer (score -2):

This identity does hold true

express both the RHS and LHS as integrals

then interchange the integrals and summations.

Hope this helps